# Missing sessionDidReceiveChallenge in Alamofire 5 delegate Swift5

Tags: swift4, alamofire, swift5

I need to convert to swift 5, because my project is deprecated and I need to update this function ... any ideas?

Due to Apple's policies, which start in December ... The logic I had in the project using the Alamofire swift 4 library passed to Swift 5 and I have problems adapting this function due to the non-existent delegate.

```
func acceptInvalidSSLCerts() {
    
    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default

    manager.delegate.sessionDidReceiveChallenge = { session, challenge in
        var disposition: URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition = .performDefaultHandling
        var credential: URLCredential?

        if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust {
            disposition = .useCredential
            credential = URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
        } else {
            if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
                disposition = .cancelAuthenticationChallenge
            } else {
                credential = manager.session.configuration.urlCredentialStorage?.defaultCredential(for: challenge.protectionSpace)

                if credential != nil {
                    disposition = .useCredential
                }
            }
        }

        return (disposition, credential)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal here? It's hard to translate code when you don't say what it's for.

Comment: Used by Alamofire to accept unsigned SSL certificates

Comment: Alamofire 5 provides a solution for that, you don't need to implement this delegate method yourself.